Windows Forms databinding to textbox with decimal value
I am trying to apply the MVVM pattern to traditional windows forms design. I have a textbox that hold a decimal value and I want to bind it to view model's Amount property.
When I enter numbers in the textbox, the Amount property get's changed without issue. However, when I Remove all the input from the textbox, the Amount property setter is not called and therefore the amount is still the previous value.
I think because the empty string is not valid decimal value, the setter is not called. I have tried to define the amount as string and that worked. Is there any way to solve this issue without having to define Amount property as string?
My viewmodel code:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    internal partial class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private decimal? _amount;

        public decimal? Amount
        {
            get => _amount;
            set
            {
                if (_amount == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _amount = value;

                // Notify the UI that the property has changed.
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        // Notify the UI that one of the properties has changed.
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

My Form.cs code:
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form7 : Form
    {
        private ViewModel _viewModel;
        public Form7()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new ViewModel();
        }

        private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(_viewModel, null);
            txtAmount.DataBindings.Add(nameof(txtAmount.Text), bindingSource, nameof(_viewModel.Amount), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null, "C2");
        }
    }
}


You can probably specify that an empty string is the null value in the binding (instead of null, otherwise the default parser won't allow to pass validation, and you get stuck). You may also want to consider replacing a null value with 0.0M in the ViewModel, but that's up to you. It depends on what you want to store and also what you want to see in the TextBox

Thanks, Jimi. You are correct. Setting the null value as empty string in the binding fix the issue. I also noticed that I have to set the formatting flag to true in the binding. If I set it to false and the textbox lost the focus, the value entered will be wiped out. It is kind of strange.

That's not exactly strange, it's what you asked for. When you set FormattingEnabled = true, you instruct to use a Formatter to parse, format and validate the value, using the current IFormatProvider. If you set it to false, then no default parsing and formatting is applied, and you're exchanging strings with numeric values

You can specify you want to parse and format the value(s) yourself, creating a Binding object that you can feed to .DataBindings.Add(), and then subscribing to its Parse and Format events. In any case, something has to do this, since you're in fact asking for data conversion, which needs to match the current (or the desired) IFormatProvider
